# Concat all files in directory tree into single file with paths separators

Tags: linux, bash, macos

As example, I have the following structure

```
mydir/a/fileA.txt
mydir/b/fileB.js
mydir/fileC.js
```

- fileA.txt content: `Im file A`
- fileB.txt content: `Im file B`
- fileC.txt content: `Im file C`

And I want to concat content of all files in `mydir` directory (recursively) into `output.txt` - line before each file content there shoud be included this separator (as first line) `---next-file->>>:` and path to this file (starting from mydir/..) wrapped by new lines. So the desired output for above example should be

```
---next-file->>>: mydir/a/fileA.txt

Im file A

---next-file->>>: mydir/b/fileB.js

Im file B

---next-file->>>: mydir/fileC.js

Im file C
```

I tried the below code but don't have any idea how to include separators with each file path

```
find mydir/ -exec cat {} \; > output.txt
```

Comment: `tail mydir/*/* mydir/*` does something pretty close out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should be POSIXly correct :

```
find mydir -type f -exec echo -n '---next-file->>>: ' \; -print -exec echo \; -exec cat {} \; -exec echo \; > output.txt
```

You can try it [here](https://ideone.com/TeKPxM).

---

A cleaner solution if you can use GNU find :

```
find mydir -type f -printf '---next-file->>>: %p\n\n' -exec cat {} \; -printf '\n' > output.txt
```

`%p` in the `-printf` format refers to the file's relative path.

You can try it [here](https://ideone.com/eT8rX2).

Answer (score 1):

For the text insertions between `cat` commands, use multiple `-exec`s.

```
find -type f -exec echo '---next-file->>>:' {}  \; -exec echo "" \; -exec cat {} \; -exec echo "" \;
```

Answer (score 1):

How's this?

```
find mydir/ -type f -exec sh -c '
    for f; do
        printf '--- %s ->>>:\n\n' "$f"
        cat "$f"
        printf '\n'
    done' _ {} +
```

This should create just one subprocess per file, plus one for `find` itself and one for `sh` (more shells if you find more files than `find` can pass to a subprocess in one go).